# Не читается полностью текстовый файл, помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Tags: c#, файлы

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот пытаюсь распарсить тестовый файл (139Кб), но он весь не читается почему то или может быть в консоли не все показывается?
Проверить можно посмотрев выводятся ли строки вида:

```
[3516] 03-26 02:05:26:264: InitializeRasmanMonitorThread Entered ...
```

в общем те строки, которые имеют цифры 03-26 (у меня нет этих строк в консоли)

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = System.IO.File.OpenText(@"F:\Project\CCC_RASMANCS.LOG"))
{
    char[] buf = new char[1024]; // пробовал делать буфер больше char[100000024] - без изменений, все равно не весь файл показывает.

    int chars_read; // Количество прочитанных символов

    while ( (chars_read = sr.ReadBlock(buf, 0, 1024)) != 0)
    sb.Append(buf, 0, chars_read);
}

// Выводим прочитанное в консоль
Console.Write(sb);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Сам файл для примера [вот](http://rghost.ru/37066395)  ([зеркало](http://medvedov.net/CCC_RASMANCS.LOG) на всякий случай)

С помощью вот такого способа тоже не весь читается:

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("CCC_RASMANCS.LOG");

    System.Console.WriteLine("Contents of writeText.txt = {0}", text);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

и таким способом тоже не весь читается:

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("CCC_RASMANCS.LOG");
        System.Console.WriteLine("Contents of CCC_RASMANCS.LOG =:");
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t" + line);
        }
        System.Console.ReadLine();
```

и таким способом не весь читается:

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("CCC_RASMANCS.LOG");
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
        file.Close();
```

и таким способом не весь читается:

```
System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream("CCC_RASMANCS.LOG", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
        System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream);
        string str = reader.ReadToEnd();
        stream.Close();
        Console.WriteLine(str);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

и таким способом не весь читается:

```
foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadLines("CCC_RASMANCS.LOG"))
        {      
                Console.WriteLine(line);   
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

ааааааааааааааааааа помогите!! *уже нервный тик*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо моему другу Барбариану, который помог мне в решении этой задачи. 
Видимо все дело в консоли, наверно есть какие то  ограничения объем показанного текста.
Выполнив команду

```
имя_приложения.exe > log.txt
```

весь текст из консоли успешно записался в log.txt
Использовался следующий вариант чтения:

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("CCC_RASMANCS.LOG");

    System.Console.WriteLine("Contents of writeText.txt = {0}", text);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

Ну, во первых, ваш буфер 1КБ, а файл 139КБ, поэтому полностью файл вы просто не прочитаете.
А во-вторых, воспользуйтесь функцией [File.ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx)

Comment: Обновил пост, не читается весь текст этим способом тоже(

Comment: А этот файл пока вы его читаете закрыт? или открыт другим приложением, которое в него что-то пишет?

Comment: Не, ничем не открыт. Вот сейчас даже перезагружусь, малоли. Upd: и после перзагрузки так же. Да Вы сами попробуйте, может это у меня одного так?